# Get Value of a specific cell in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

I have a DataGrid. Now I want to have the data from a particular cell for some comparison purpose. For that I have found the rowindex of that cell. And I want the data from second column. So far my code in KeyDown event of datagrid looks like below :

```
DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
{
    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
}

if (dep == null)
    return;

if (dep is DataGridCell)
{
    //cancel if datagrid in edit mode
    maindg.CancelEdit();


    //Check if selected cell is on second column and last row
    if (maindg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 1)
    {
        DependencyObject depObj = dep;

        //Find Row to which selectedCell belongs
        while ((depObj != null) && !(depObj is DataGridRow))
        {
            depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
        }

        DataGridRow selectedCellRow = depObj as DataGridRow;
        if (FindRowIndex(selectedCellRow) == maindg.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            if (Here I want to check if cell's value is null or empty)
            {
                btnSave.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched for this question on google. But everywhere I get the value of the selected cell. Suppose I want to find the value of a cell which belongs to row 5 and column 4, then how can I find that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the code below, it will get you the cell.

```
if (selectedCellRow != null)
{
    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(selectedCellRow);
    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
    var cellValue = cell.Content;
}
```

Comment: I get an error : The non-generic method 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetVisualChild(int)' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: This will give me the cell object back. But I want its value.

Comment: Thanks. I was checking for Text Property.